# How to mathematically compute the volatility range of each stock?

Tags: equities, quant-trading-strategies, technical-analysis, technicals

I joined a stock market group and in this stock group, there is a proprietary "daily trading range (or DTR)" that the founder uses. However in order to do this for all the hundreds of stocks in the stock market, he has to have a way to determine the volatility range mathematically.

Below is an example of the daily trading range in full form.
[image: Amibroker version]

I'll also attach the Excel file with the proprietary DTR (Please refer to the "DTR" worksheet or the 3rd worksheet and it is located at the bottom area). The support levels are labeled: Line in Sand, Buy Trade 2, and Buy Trade 1. The resistance levels are labeled: Sell Trade 1, Sell Trade 2, and Blue Skies if above.
[Excel File](https://ufile.io/f74op)

Below is a video of how volatility trading ranges work: [Volatility ranges at work](https://vimeo.com/306613030/ba30b151cc)

Comment: Do Fibonacci numbers have any value in trading? Just wondering...

Comment: I've been observing stock behavior relative to the fibonacci numbers. They work surprisingly well. They are used as supports and resistances. It appears a bit unscientific because of the nature of the fibonacci numbers. I also doubted it at first but it seems to hold true more often than it does not